# Formula Field or Flow?

Tags: formula

I am trying to decide if I need a formula with a return type of text, or a flow to make this work. I have 4 different scenarios that 1.) need to mark a checkbox as true if ANY conditions are met, and 2.) display a certain text depending on which sceanrio made the checkbox true. I have the following formula field with the return type of text (which currently isn't working).

```
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +15, "DIY LINKEDIN REVIEW NOT COMPLETE",
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +60, "NOT CERTIFIED",
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +150, "VOLUNTEER PROJECT COMPLETE",
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +180, "JOB NOT LANDED"))
```

Any ideas on this? Was thinking if I could get this formula field to work, I could create a checkbox that marks as true if this formula field (called At Risk Reason) is NOT blank. Thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Or wrong text in that field. Please provide details of problem you are facing.

Comment: I get this: Error: Syntax Error. Missing ')'

Comment: Just to point out that anything that generates a message like this that you intend to present to the user is a bad idea if you ever need to support multiple languages.

Comment: @PhilW That can easily be solved by  using Custom labels.

Comment: @user853710, via the use of `$Label.Some_Label_Here`, I assume you mean. Sure, doable (just so long as you don't need to do anything clever like support mailmerge). I was simply pointing this problem out.

Comment: @PhilW should also be doable using label($Label.Some_Label_Here__c)

Comment: Yes, and I already agreed with you on that, though pointing out mailmerge issues (i.e. if you have a label value like "Substitute a {0} here" where "{0}" is to be replaced by a value, this will be difficult to handle). Never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only problem is your structure.

Try:

```
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +15, "DIY LINKEDIN REVIEW NOT COMPLETE",
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +60, "NOT CERTIFIED",
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +150, "VOLUNTEER PROJECT COMPLETE",
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +180, "JOB NOT LANDED", ""))))
```

Note the extra `)`s and the `""` at the end. Explanation follows:

The format of the `IF` statment is:

```
IF( CONDITION, TRUE_CONDITION, FALSE_CONDITION)
```

You can nest them, where the `false` condition becomes a whole new `if` statement like:

```
IF( CONDITION, TRUE_CONDITION, 
  IF( CONDITION, TRUE_CONDITION, FALSE_CONDITION)
)
```

Your formula, nested looks like:

```
IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +15, "DIY LINKEDIN REVIEW NOT COMPLETE", 
  IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +60, "NOT CERTIFIED", 
    IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +150, "VOLUNTEER PROJECT COMPLETE", 
      IF(TODAY() >  Sign_Up_Date__c +180, "JOB NOT LANDED", "")
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Also the last `IF` had no `ELSE` condition